# How to assign a value in const unordered_map to another const variable - C++

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void fun(const unordered_map<int, vector<int>>& direct_paths) {
    const int var = direct_paths[1][0];
    cout << var;
}

int main()
{
    unordered_map<int, vector<int>> a;
    a[1] = vector<int> {1,2,3};
    fun(a);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code outputs the following error:

```
error: passing ‘const std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int> >’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  const int var = direct_paths[1][0];
                                ^
```

Where as The below code doesn't output any compilation error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void fun(const vector<int>& direct_paths) {
    const int var = direct_paths[1];
    cout << var;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> a;
    a = vector<int> {1,2,3};
    fun(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Questions:

1. Can I assign the value in a key-value pair of an unordered_map somehow?
2. Why is assigning an integer from vector taken from const unordered_map<int, vector&> disallowed? & from const vector allowed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try a more simple example of using [ ] on a `const map`. The problem is that it may create a new item in the map. Thus cannot be const.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) of a `std::(unordered_)map` is a non-`const` operator only, as it will modify the map to insert a new element if the requested key is not found.  But inside of `fun()`, `direct_paths` is (a reference to) a `const` map object, so `operator[]` cannot be called on it.  That is what the compiler is complaining about, as you can't call non-`const` methods on `const` objects.

The [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) of `std::vector` has no such limitation, as it is overloaded to work with both `const` and non-`const` vector objects.

To fix the error you are seeing, you will need to use the map's [`at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/at) or [`find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) method instead, which can both be called on `const` map objects, eg:

```cpp
void fun(const unordered_map<int, vector<int>>& direct_paths) {
    const int var = direct_paths.at(1)[0]; // will throw an exception if key '1' is not found...
    cout << var;
}
```

```
void fun(const unordered_map<int, vector<int>>& direct_paths) {
    auto iter = direct_paths.find(1); // will return the end() iterator if key '1' is not found...
    if (iter == direct_paths.end()) return; // or throw...
    const int var = iter->second[0];
    cout << var;
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why accessing a nonexistent member through `vector::operator[]` is UB but `unordered_map` simply declines to have `const operator[]` at all? Desire to avoid UB, but not able to do so in `vector` because of commitment to mimicing array-like unchecked access through `operator[]`?

Comment: "*Is there a particular reason why ...*" - ask the C++ standards committee.

Comment: @NathanPierson A vector is basically "dynamic *array*". And arrays are a contiguous collection of elements, and `std::vector` implements the same semantics. Allowing any random index would break the array-like semantics.

Comment: @NathanPierson Not sure what you're suggesting might have been defined instead. Give `unordered_map` a const-qualified `operator[]` which has UB or throws on nonexistent key? Having const and non-const versions of something act so differently would be a dangerous violation of the Principle of Least Surprise.

Comment: @aschepler UB on nonexistent key, analogous to `operator[]` in `vector`. I suppose non-`const` `operator[]` is already quite different from non-`const` `operator[]` in `vector` though since it's capable of performing insertions, so "make the containers' APIs more analogous" isn't very convincing.

Comment: @NathanPierson my way of getting along with this inconsistency is to accept that `unordered_map::operator[]` is not element access, rather it is element access and insertion. Its a good reminder of why one needs to be careful with operator overloading ;)